# What is the method called when the URI('http://google.com') start?

Tags: ruby

Almost all of you used `URI` module to convert a url string to an object in order to make some validation or change.

Example:

```rb
require 'uri'

URI('https://google.com')
# => #<URI::HTTPS https://google.com>
```

As you can see, the result is the `HTTPS` object under the `URI` module.
So, there is a question what is run when you write module/class name with round braces like the line of code above.
I thought, it is implicit calling of `call` method, but I got `NoMethodError`.

Example:

```rb
class MyClass
  def self.call
    puts 'You were right!'
  end
end

MyClass()
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `MyClass' for main:Object
```

Comment: How does the title fit the actual question and code? Nowhere do you use a URI.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you *exactly* what the name of the method is.

Comment: @theTinMan, sorry for misunderstanding. I thought, example in the title and code in the body are obvious to understand. Sorry again.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I read the message but still didn't get how it's possible, because `MyClass` is a class, not a method. And I supposed there is a trick in implementation. Sorry for misunderstanding. I hope, next time my question will be more clear.

Comment: @OleksiiPyvovar it's important you fix this question, not next time. Stack Overflow is like an online encyclopedia of programming problems and their solutions, where each question is a new article. As is, this article is being flagged for deletion by SO users because it doesn't meet the guidelines. By fleshing out the question so it makes more sense you can avoid that. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Comment: @theTinMan, thank you again and beg a pardon.

Comment: "I read the message but still didn't get how it's possible" – The message says that it can't find a method named `MyClass`. So, what is the logical thing to do when the error message says that you are missing a method of a certain name? If you get a message saying ``NoMethodError: undefined method `foo'``, how do you fix it?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, you are right, you need to define the method that is undefined.

Comment: But, as @Richard-Degenne said, naming methods after class/module name is a very bad practice, because it leads to misunderstanding. There was a conflict in my mind, because I've never seen such a code before. Now I know that `uri` module patches `Kernel` to bring a `URI()` method (thanks to @max-pleaner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny enough, with the code you've shown, `MyClass.()` works (which is an alias for `.call`).

However in the case of URI, this actually a method (methods can begin with capitals).  You can see the source code here: https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/URI/instance

Comment: I would argue that this is a very bad practice, though. It breaks legibility, and people (such as OP) may think that this is a class being called or something.

Comment: @max-pleaner, thank you to pointing me, will dig further. I definitely need to revise my ruby knowledge.
Actually, I didn't expect that method can be named exactly like the module/class. Now I need to understand how ruby resolves it under the hood

Comment: @Richard-Degenne, totally agree with you. It's really confusing thing.